# Store: Member has ability to download order information

Tags: expresso-store

Question has nothing to do with the product download tag.

How do I enable a member to download their order information without access to the CP? Just like the report generation in the Store CP, but I want to do this on a member level on a per order basis on the front-end of the website when the member is logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest and probably one of the easiest ways is to use an add-on like [PDF Press](http://dvt.ee/pdfprss) to easily create a PDF for download using the Store Orders tag pair.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you just want to display the customers orders on the front end of the site (say in the customers account area) use Expresso-Stores `{exp:store:orders}` tags as Justin says, but use them on a template . Full documentation of the tag pair is here : https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/orders_tag.html